# How to use variable name in object?

Tags: javascript, object, var

I want to access the value of my object but with a `.var`. 
For example, if I specifiy the full path by myself it's `apple = theApples.trees.green` but I want to do:

```
var colorOfApple = "red";
apple = theApples.trees.colorOfApple;
```

the problem is it tries to access `.colorOfApple` of the object but I want to have the value of `colorOfApple`

Comment: Use bracket notation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Sorry for the dup, I didn't found this answer before. I'll give more attention next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple, just `apple = theApples.trees[colorOfApple];`

Comment: ufff I need to go in weekend, thank you so much